# How to write a Navigator object standard W3C proposal?

Tags: browser, w3c, navigator

Based on the [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp): "**There is no public standard that applies to the navigator object, but all major browsers support it.**".

I somehow see the navigator object as rather important, and with the rate at which browsers change their versions today even more so. So it rather baffles me that there is no standard for it.

What baffles me even more is that none of the browsers seem to have come up with the idea to include the two most important properties into this object:

```
navigator.browserName
navigator.browserVersion
```

We all have to parse the darn navigator.userAgent and hope from version to version that stuff in there did not change too much. *Like it just did in IE11 for example...*

**How can one even write a W3C proposal for a new standard?**

Comment: You begin by starting a [W3C Community Group](http://www.w3.org/community/) and getting the relevant stakeholders interested.

Comment: But w3schools is wrong *again*. Here's the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-navigator-object)

Comment: Thanks @alohci, how did you find it? I Googled it without success...
Anywho, so now the question is how to change that standard and include some useful information?

Comment: Actually I found it via the MDN page for the navigator object. But I should have just known from reading the spec. If you want changes, you can raise bugs on the HTML5 spec. However, the browser makers don't want you doing browser specific things, so don't hold much hope.

Comment: I know, but since the justification for the Navigator object states: "This section defines a collection of attributes that can be used to determine, from script, the kind of user agent in use, in order to work around these issues." I believe this information should be readily available and we should not have to jump through hoops to determine which browser our code is being executed in... I will try at least...

Comment: Also, does anyone know whats the purpose of the appCodeName and product attributes which are set in stone to be "Mozilla" and "Gecko" regardless of the actual browser? And the appVersion is what it is in all browsers because the alternative set in the standard is fixed to be "4.0" regardless of the actual browser version. It's either specifically "4.0" OR the detailed cluttered text... Weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alohci and some more digging, since [the Navigator object has a standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-navigator-object), the way to go about proposing a change to it is to send an email to the public-html@w3.org